# how can i compile a java program to run from a given folder?

Tags: java, linux, jar, terminal, javac

I have a java program `Test.java` located at `/path/to/parent` on a CentOS 7 server.  **How can I compile it so that the resulting `.class` or `.jar` file can be called succesfully from `/path/to/parent` using the `java` command?**  I am trying to leave `/path/to/parent` as clean as possible without cluttering it with files that can be put in subdirectories.  Also note that the program requires many dependencies, which are located in `/path/to/parent/dependencies/`

Here is what I have so far:

The code for `Test.java` is:

```
package somepackage;  

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < args.length; ++index){
            System.out.println("args[" + index + "]: " + args[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

When the terminal is pointed to `/path/to/parent/` , I type the following to complile `Test.java`:

```
javac -d bin -cp .:"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*" Test.java
```

I am then able to navigate to `/path/to/parent/bin` and successfully run the program by typing the following:

```
java -cp .:"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*" somepackage.Test arg0 arg1
```

However, I am **NOT** able to run the program from `/path/to/parent` because attempting to do so gives the error: `Could not find or load main class somepackage.Test`.  **So how can I change the above so that I can call the program successfully from `/path/to/parent` using the `java` command, and without cluttering `/path/to/parent`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java -cp "/path/to/parent/bin":"/path/to/parent/dependencies/*" mainpackage.Test arg0 arg1` to run it.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for providing a correct answer quickly.